# Help me understand why my edit was rejected

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, edits, rejected-edits

I edited an answer this morning — I think it's worth noting that this is actually my first **answer** edit — and it was rejected (3 out of 5 voted '*Reject*').

The review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/5272793

All three people who chose to reject provided this explanation:

> This edit is incorrect or an attempt to reply to or comment on the existing post.

Now, I'm not actually saying they are wrong, but I would like to understand exactly why, so that I don't repeat this in the future.

The way I see it:

- **Answers**: are used to answer the question,
- **Comments on questions**: are used to make it clearer, ask more info, propose suggestions and diagnostics,
- **Comments on answers**: are there to add minor precision, raise interrogation, discuss something about the answer or the way it addresses the question.

Now, I usually edit **questions** to make them clearer or add information that I could make out from the poster.

If you take a look at the second example in the answer I tried to edit, it seems wrong to me. From my point of view, what is said is wrong or inaccurate at best.

I posted a small comment (because I did not take the time to type it into the interpreter). Then someone corrected my own comment, and after I acknowledged it was indeed an improvement, I tested the code sample in my Python interpreter and only *then* proposed the edit.

I'm not sure what is "incorrect" about what I wrote, it is not a "reply", and I obviously didn't intend to "comment" since I had done that already. On the contrary, I sincerely thought I was improving this answer. And after all, 2 people agreed with me.

Now, I'd like to have your opinion as to why I am wrong. Maybe what I wrote *was* incorrect, but I can't see why at the moment.

Here is the post (to see the comments): https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689983/

Comment: You reworded nearly the whole last paragraph and added a second one. If you think a user needs to update their answer to correct what you believe is wrong, then you comment saying so and that's it. You do not reword an answer to what you think it should say. Basically the reject message is saying the person who made the edit should have instead made a comment or reply.

Comment: @PatrickEvans Okay, I can understand that, but then what is the point of answer edits. I have seen many people have their edits be rejected because they were too minor... I am beginning to wonder what would be a good answer edit. Would you have adequate examples?

Comment: The same as question edits, [edit help page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), but I guess your edit could fall under the second or third items in the _"When should I edit posts"_. In the case of the second item, the meaning of the post was already clear, in my opinion it is anyway. For the third item yea you added information from the comments but I think that most programmers would already know that `x` was the iteration variable and that its value is changed each iteration.

Comment: As for an examples: Fixing any out of date documentation links the user may have used. The poster of the answer and you are commenting and they provide a link to a demo (like jsfiddle for javascript demos) in the comments but does not add it to the answer, I think if the demo is relevant then editing the answer to include it would be valid as it is covered under the third point about adding additional information

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time and for the explanation.

Comment: I believe I came across this in the review queue, and skipped it because I thought it was very much borderline, and wasn't sure how to vote. The 3-2 vote confirms that it was not a clear cut case. It definitely looked like a legitimate attempt to improve the answer. But the edit was more intrusive to the original answer than usual. While you certainly did this edit with the best intentions, I think it would have been a better choice to leave a comment suggesting that the author of the answer make the improvement.

Comment: Please do not use `back ticks` for `emphasis`; they're here for adding code.

Comment: @Tonio "Too minor" means that the changes are not extensive enough not that the changes are too minor.

Comment: Yes, indeed. Please *never* use backticks for emphasis. Use bold and/or italics instead.

Comment: @Elin, and/or that there are blatant or obvious mistakes/improvements that should have been made to the post that the editor missed/ignored. Once you get +2k rep feel free to make small edits as you only use up your own time. Until then any edit you make uses up reviewers' time too and should be substantial enough to bother them with.

Comment: That's what I mean by "not extensive enough" .. when I review edits usually if I see that I select Improve, but half the time they get approved while I'm improving.

Comment: @LéoLam Sure, sorry for that. And thank you everyone, I think your comments helped me understand and will help me in future edits.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In some cases, an edit like this might be acceptable. The 3-2 vote to reject supports @Bradley's position that this edit was borderline, to some extent (small sample). That said, I would have rejected it without a second thought.

Let's start by looking at [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24689967/2359271). Specifically, what type of answer is the asker looking for?

> This is more of a conceptual question. I recently saw a piece of code ... which strikes me as both bad practice and something that should not work at all.
>
> ...
>
> What's going on under the hood that allows something like this to work?

This user is really asking you to *explain in your own words*. Even the top-voted answer, which contains probably the best objective response possible (the disassembled bytecode), has some *explanation* of what it presents. In this situation, the phrasing of the answer is particularly important, because the question is *help me understand* and not *give me a solution* or *find the error*.

So the key to me is that the answerer *explained in their own words*, and that constitutes real content of their post, which should not be removed in an edit. If you thought their wording was deficient, that would have justified a comment or a downvote, but nothing more. If you thought you had a better way to explain it, the appropriate place for *your own words* would have been in *your own answer* - or, you can always suggest your alternative phrasing in a comment, leaving it up to the answerer to adopt those words or not.

This is not just a quirk of Stack Overflow, it's fundamental to the entire concept of *editing* as distinct from *collaborating*. If the answer had been a Community Wiki you would have had a lot more leeway, and this edit would have been fully justified, in your capacity as a *collaborator*. But your job as an *editor* is to help deliver the other user's content, **not** to deliver your own content in its place.

Since what constitutes the content of an answer can be subjective or hard to decide, let me suggest a useful heuristic: Take another look at your suggested edit and note the before-and-after. Sit back, unfocus your eyes a bit, what you see is *a big red block turning into a big green block*. That's a good indication that your edit may not be appropriate.

---

**As far as what *is* appropriate in an edit:** Obvious typos, broken markup code, and purely grammatical errors - punctuation, capitalization, spelling - should be fixed *whenever* editing. When someone cites a specific external resource, you might add an inline link. When someone provides a useful link but only *refers* to its content, it might be appropriate to insert a block quote with one specifically relevant sentence, paragraph or snippet from, to protect against link rot. In the case of questions, there's also retagging and replacing titles like "help i cant fix error" with titles that actually describe the question.

Comment: Yes, I think I understand what you mean. It is true that changing the meaning of a post should not be permitted. After all if that's what the user wants to say, it is as it should be. Comments and votes will do the rest.

Answer (score 12):

This is borderline acceptable to me. It's not a *drastic* change, but I can see why people would reject it.

I might instead post a comment saying something like ("*This piece doesn't seem clear, perhaps you could say <insert new text>*."). Often the OP will edit in himself or say you can do so. At least the OP has some input in the matter.

In general, you don't change the content of a post in an edit. Doing so can change the solution or problem. You were just clarifying (and did so well), so it's borderline. It is something to keep in mind for the future though.

Comment: As I just commented on @AirThomas's answer, I now understand that editing should not modify the meaning of the answer in the sense that it could be seen as an infringement on people's expression. I now understand that this is not the purpose of edits. Their purpose is to clarify the post or make it more compliant with the site standards.