# The "How to Edit" section should also clarify what not to do

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, edits

I recently edited an answer by adding some additional code I found helpful to solving the problem.  I thought my edit fell under the "clarify meaning without changing it." After my edit was rejected, I see that the best practice is to add a new answer that builds on top of the original answer because adding code to someone else's answer is frowned upon.

When editing an answer, some best practices are listed to the right:

*How to Edit*

- *fix grammatical or spelling errors*
- *clarify meaning without changing it*
- *correct minor mistakes*
- *add related resources or links*
- *always respect the original author*

I think it would be helpful if some do nots were listed as well, such as

- Do not add new or original content
- Do not modify the author's code (except for formatting changes)
- Do not change the meaning of the post
- Do not converse within a post
- Anything else an edit should not do?

And, based on feedback, adding something like the following may help reduce multiple edits to the same answer:

- Make all changes in one edit

I also think it would be helpful if the review process was explained up front.  I was not aware that my edit would require approval until after I submitted the edit.

It is frustrating when one thinks they are being helpful but instead discover they broke some unwritten rules.

Resources:

- [Why was my edit rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284781/why-was-my-edit-rejected)
- [When should I make edits to code?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code)
- [Clear rules on reviewing edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/175298/clear-rules-on-reviewing-edits)
- [Help me understand why my edit was rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265332/help-me-understand-why-my-edit-was-rejected?rq=1)
- [Why are the following suggested edits being rejected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267076/why-are-the-following-suggested-edits-being-rejected?rq=1)

Comment: Also under How to Edit, please fix _all problems_ in a single edit.  Or something to that effect.

Comment: @ryanyuyu: Closer to "all problems you can", but yes.

Comment: @NathanTuggy oddly enough, I was originally going to write that.  I just wasn't sure it was assertive enough.

Comment: I disagree with '(except for formatting changes)'.  Formatting is something you really *shouldn't* ever touch.

Comment: @sapi, I disagree. Code is unreadable when it is not properly formatted as a code block. Indenting it properly is nice too.

Comment: @JonasCz Does not apply to python, because improper indenting is highly likely the cause of the problem.

Comment: @Artjom, yes obviously. But putting it in a code block still applies.

Comment: @JonasCz I agree about putting things in a code block, but if you go around 'improving' people's indentation, variable names, and the like you're just *asking* to start an edit war.  It's better to agree to disagree on that.

Comment: *"Do not modify the author's code (except for formatting changes)"* I do not agree with this. It's sometimes necessary to edit and there are some instances of code editing where asking the author for permission is not necessary. For example when there is an obvious variable name mismatch, a typo in a known function, etc. Writing a comment in this case only clutters up space and someone has to clean up afterwards. It's easier to make the edit and write a proper edit summary.

Comment: Only format code if you are really certain and actually know the language is used a lot as a guideline.

Comment: I wouldnt actually change anyone's actual code. The only thing I'd ever do is put it in a code block, and indent it properly if it's really egregious (and not Python ).

Comment: @ryanyuyu: What do you think about the _Make all changes in one edit_ I added to the question?  Or do you still prefer modifying the first line?

Comment: The _(except for formatting changes)_ was influenced by the first answer on a [different post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260245/when-should-i-make-edits-to-code), which had 60 upvotes.  Would it be better to remove this line and replace it with an asterisk and then at the bottom of the page add a description with something like: "_Code edits are likely to be rejected except for moving the code into code blocks or properly indenting in some cases. If the code is incorrect, add a comment and/or downvote the answer instead of editing._"

Comment: @JustinFisher that seems like a fine addendum.

Comment: One more: "Don't edit an answer into a question -- post an answer instead."